# Socket error with uWSGI

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi, wsgi

I am trying to run uwsgi.ini file with
`uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini` and it gives me an error

`The -s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket.`

```
[wsgi.ini]
socket=0.0.0.0:8001
chdir=/home/ubuntu/appname
module=appname.wsgi:application
pidfile=/home/ubuntu/myproject.pid
vacuum=true
```

When I run

`uwsgi --module=appname.wsgi:application --chdir=/home/ubuntu/appname --socket=0.0.0.0:8001`

It all works just fine, but confused why is this so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ini section must be [uwsgi] not [wsgi.ini]. If you want to use a different section you have to instruct uwsgi about it using the file:section syntax: uwsgi --ini file.ini:thenewsection